# Remove an element from a list of lists Haskell

Tags: list, haskell

I' am trying to remove an element from a list of lists, but only if the element is on a list with length 1. For example:

```
removeElement 1 [[2,3],[1,2],[1]]  
                [[2,3],[1,2]]

removeElement 2 [[1,2,3,4]] 
                [[1,2,3,4]]

removeElement 3 [[3],[1,4,5]] 
                [[1,4,5]]
```

So far I have this, but I don't know how to continue, or which function use.

```
removeElement :: (Eq a) => a -> [[a]] -> [[a]]
removeElement a [[]] = []
removeElement a ((x:xs):rs) = if a == x then (xs:rs) else  [x] :( removeElement a (xs:rs))
```

Comment: Hint: `removeElement a = _ [a]`. Fill in the `_` with a simpler, more common function, that doesn't need to be aware that it's operating on a list of lists.

Comment: shouldn't a `filter` be enough for this? `filter ((/=1) . length)`

Comment: @Chase - not quite, as the OP doesn't want to remove all singleton lists, just ones holding a specific element

Comment: @RobinZigmond oh I see, I suppose that would be `filter (/=[x])` then

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an example of [filtering](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:filter):

```hs
removeElement :: Eq a => a -> [[a]] -> [[a]]
removeElement e = filter (/= [e])
```

Testing your examples with ghci:

```
> removeElement 1 [[2,3],[1,2],[1]]
[[2,3],[1,2]]
> removeElement 2 [[1,2,3,4]]
[[1,2,3,4]]
> removeElement 3 [[3],[1,4,5]]
[[1,4,5]]
```